# Autofilter compile error: expected instruction

Tags: excel, vbscript, autofilter

This code fails with error

> line 18 character 54 ,expected instruction , compiled error vbscipt

at this line

`xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$730").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array(2, "11/4/2019")`

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample


Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

    Dim xlApp 
    Dim xlBook 

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Z:\DDDDDD.XLS", 0, True) 

    xlApp.Cells.Select
    xlApp.Selection.AutoFilter     
    xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$730").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array(2, "11/4/2019")
    xlApp.Selection.Copy
    xlApp.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    xlApp.ActiveSheet.Paste

    xlBook.CheckCompatibility = False
    xlBook.SaveAs "pathe\Escritorio\filename.xlsx"

    xlApp.Quit 

    Set xlBook = Nothing 
    Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Comment: How does it fail? Is there some kind of error message?

Comment: line 18 character 54 ,expected instruction , compiled error vbscipt

Comment: in this line xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$730").AutoFilter Field:=4

Comment: the syntaxis is wrong

Comment: `On Error resume next` needs to be in a Sub or Function.  Did you add a reference to the Excel object library in your VB project?  Where is this code running?

Comment: You CANNOT used named parameters in VBScript. VBScript does NOT have access to parameter's names. You must use positional `FunctionName(Param1,,Param3)` note I omitted param2.